# Getting serialization exception when storing a list of object to session variable

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a form which I want to store input field values to session variables. The form is used to create new user: an admin user would put in an username of new user, go to next page to add other info, and then create the user. So, I want to store the info they put on the first page to session variables to be able to use it later. Problem is that I'm getting a serialization exception.

This is the ajax I'm using, when going from first page to second page:

```
function holdUserData() {
    //pass in username and a list of club IDs
    var data = {
        username: $('#tbUsername').val(), 
        clubs: this.clubs
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Users/GoManageClub', //store in GoManageClub controller
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            //redirect to ManageClubAccess controller when done
            window.location = '/Users/ManagClubAccess';
        }
    })
}
```

And my `GoManageClub` controller, storing the data to session:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GoManagePolicy(string username, List<ClubVM> clubs)
{
    Session["Username"] = username;
    Session["Clubs"] = clubs;

    return this.Json(new { success = true });
}
```

When I only store the username string, there are no problems and the variable is successfully stored. But when I'm storing the `List<ClubVM>`, I get the serialization exception:

```
Type 'myOrganization.ClubVM' in Assembly 'myorg, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable
```

My `ClubVM`:

```
public class ClubVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    /* ... */
}
```

What should I do so I can save `List<ClubVM> clubs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class to be serialized needs a [Serializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute.

This indicates that you intend for the class to be serialized (stored as set of bytes.) That's what happens when you save an object to `Session`. Depending on the implementation of `Session` the object could be stored in memory or it could be saved to a database.

```
[Serializable()]
public class ClubVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    /* ... */
}
```

Value types like `int` are already serializable. But if `ClubVM` contains references to other types then those types must also be serializable unless you mark them with a `NonSerialized` attribute. And so on. But if you mark something `NonSerialized` that means that when you deserialize the object (retrieve it from `Session`) that property will be missing because it wasn't included when the rest of the object was serialized.

Comment: 1) "Serialized" means creating a JSON or XML representation of the object. It's not a "set of bytes". 2) Objects stored in memory (In Proc) do not need to be serialized. It's only an issue if your session store is something like SQL Server.

Comment: Serialization includes binary serialization. It's not limited to JSON or XML. It very well may be a "set of bytes." It's significant regardless of how `Session` is serialized. You don't want your application to stop working because you change your `SessionState` implementation.

Comment: That's a very real scenario, BTW. I worked on an app that had a massive, non-serializable class that it stored in `Session`. It had all sorts of crazy dependencies. Then we tried to implement SQL-based `SessionState` and couldn't without rewriting half of the app. We had to modify our load balancing to ensure that users always stayed on the same server where their state was stored in memory. And anything forced them to switch servers they lost their session.

Comment: Sounds like an absolute awful design to me. Storing a massive, unserializable object in the session is a fairly obvious abuse of sessions, and almost assuredly should have been handled in another way.

Comment: It was an awful design and egregious abuse of `Session`. The object owned dependencies on anything and everything. Even if you took `Session` out of the picture it was pretty bad. The fact that the part that needed to be serialized couldn't be extricated from the rest pretty much says it all.